# Redirect via JS with string

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I want all users who visite a specific URL to be redirected to another page. This works well, but now I want to redirect with a tracking URL.

But JS adds an "/" in front of the tacking string beginning with "?" - how can I solve this problem?

Here is my code:

```
if(document.location.href.indexOf('url-parameter') > -1) { 
    document.location.href = '/subpage?utm_source=area';
}
```

- I want the user to be send to "/subpage?utm_source=area"
- JS sends the
  user to: "/subpage/?utm_source=area"

How can I prevent JS to add the slash?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a problemen with your webserver. Can you visit the URL without using js? If not, check your apache config and htaccess files.

Why do you use document.location? I think you should use window.location.

Comment: Yes, it's working without problems without JS. I have no idea, why the "/" is added :/

Comment: Did you try window.location instead of document.location?